# Mesa OpenGL version

Tags: linux, graphics-card, intel-graphics, opengl

The output of glxinfo command is

```
 glxinfo |grep Open
    Vendor: Intel Open Source Technology Center (0x8086)
OpenGL vendor string: Intel Open Source Technology Center
OpenGL renderer string: Mesa DRI Intel(R) HD Graphics 520 (Skylake GT2) 
OpenGL core profile version string: 4.5 (Core Profile) Mesa 13.0.2
OpenGL core profile shading language version string: 4.50
OpenGL core profile context flags: (none)
OpenGL core profile profile mask: core profile
OpenGL core profile extensions:
OpenGL version string: 3.0 Mesa 13.0.2
OpenGL shading language version string: 1.30
OpenGL context flags: (none)
OpenGL extensions:
OpenGL ES profile version string: OpenGL ES 3.2 Mesa 13.0.2
OpenGL ES profile shading language version string: OpenGL ES GLSL ES 3.20
OpenGL ES profile extensions:
```

The "core profile version" is 4.5, while the "version string" is 3.0 . Which of these numbers is telling me which OpenGL version my graphic card is using?
Also, what are the ES entries for?

Comment: Mali Remorker: Did you find an answer for this? I have almost the same question: Why is there two different OpenGL versions listed for the HD4000 on Ubuntu Linux? [https://askubuntu.com/questions/941444/intel-core-i5-hd4000-two-opengl-versions-supported](https://askubuntu.com/questions/941444/intel-core-i5-hd4000-two-opengl-versions-supported)

Comment: See https://askubuntu.com/q/928538/522170 and  https://askubuntu.com/q/886548/522170 . These questions have more detailed answers. The bottomline is that the core profile is the most important one. This still doesn't guarantee that  an OpenGL v4 program(game) is going to work. I have been told that some v4 games do not work on intel HD on my CPU, because the developers thought it's behaving unstable.

Comment: @MaliRemorker Your comment should be an answer. Please read [Can I answer my own question?](https://$SITEURL$/help/self-answer)

Answer (score 1):

`OpenGL ES` is for Embedded Systems see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenGL_ES).
If you look at [Mesa release notes](https://www.mesa3d.org/relnotes/13.0.2.html) for version 13.0.2 you will see it claims to support OpenGL 4.4.
I cannot make more sense of it.